# Get rid of the solution in algebraic cubial system

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solving a system
\begin{cases} -Ay+(-2-A)xy-Ay^2-2xy^2-2x^2y=0 \\-3Ax+(3-3A)x^2-3Axy+y^2+3x^3+xy^2+y^3+3x^2y=0 \end{cases}
I got solves:
\begin{cases} x=0 \\ y=0 \end{cases} \begin{cases} x=-1 \\ y=0 \end{cases} \begin{cases} x=A \\ y=0. \end{cases}
How to get rid of root (-1,0), keeping the the other roots.

I have to do this because studying this system in the circle turns Poincare complicated point which should not be.

Comment: How do you want to "get rid of the root"? It's a degree three polynomial, it has three roots.

Comment: Otherwise, your two other pairs are solutions of the equation $xy^2(x-A)=0$, but I'm not sure that makes sense... whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: From a purely algebraic point of view you will never get rid of it simply because it is an algebraically valid solution. You will have to use some supplementary, non-algebraic assumptions, to eliminate it, but these assumptions are not in the statement of your problem. I gues you will have to provide the full context.

Comment: You could also add the constraint $x\neq -1$ by dividing the whole thing by $(x+1)$.

Comment: My task is explore the quadratic and cubic system of differential equations obtained for trisectix of Maclaurin.
The quadratic system was studied without any sample, but cubic everything was not so simple. There was a difficult point explore the who I do not know. But I can somehow get rid of it.